# F# nested generic types not compatible with implemented type

Tags: generics, f#

**Background:**

Given the following two declarations in an F# program:

- type `A` implements the interface `Wrapped<int>`
- type `B` implements the interface `Wrapped<A>`

We say that type `A` is compatible with `Wrapped<int>` and type `B` is compatible with `Wrapped<A>` - compatible, to my understanding, meaning that an `A` can be passed into a function requiring a `Wrapped<int>`.

**Problem:**

From my experience with programming, I would expect the following to also be true, given the above two statements:

- type `B` should be compatible with the type `Wrapped<Wrapped<int>>`

since `B` has `A` as the type parameter where `Wrapped<int>` should go, and `A` and `Wrapped<int>` are compatible.

This is not the case. The following implementation:

```
type Wrapper<'a> = abstract member Value : 'a

type A =
    | A of int

    interface Wrapper<int> with member this.Value = (let (A num) = this in num)

type B =
    | B of A

    interface Wrapper<A> with member this.Value = (let (B a) = this in a)


let f (x:Wrapper<Wrapper<int>>) =
    x.Value.Value

let testValue = f (B (A 1))
```

has a compile error on `B (A 1)` stating

> The type `B` is not compatible with the type `Wrapper<Wrapper<int>>`

**Question:**

Since I was able to logically make the compatibility jump, am I doing something wrong while implementing this? Or does F# not have this "nested compatibility" feature, and if that's the case, is there a particular reason for not having it?

---

There is a workaround to this:

```
type B =
    | B of A

    interface Wrapper<Wrapper<int>> with member this.Value = (let (B a) = this in a :> Wrapper<int>)
```

That will remove the compile error, though it feels a little bit wrong. I ask myself "What if I ever write a function to work on `Wrapper<A>` types? (if I ever add more `Wrapper<A>` implementers)

Comment: Your assumptions are incorrect: in F# there is no automatic subtype coercion (i.e. you can't normally pass a subtype to a function that expects supertype, unless you specifically declare the function that way), and it's not always true that `T<X> :?> T<Y>` when `X :?> Y`. This property is called "covariance" (google it), and it doesn't always hold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature you're asking for is covariant types.

Covariance permits a return type which is a subtype rather than that exactly defined by the generic type parameter (not that this is applicable only to interfaces, not concrete types). This allows you to downcast `IEnumerable<string> :?> IEnumerable<object>` as `string :?> object`.

Declaration is possible in the other .NET languages. Here's your example in C#:

```
interface Wrapper<out T> { }
class A : Wrapper<int> { }
class B : Wrapper<A> { }          

var b = new B();
Action<Wrapper<Wrapper<int>>> unwrap = _ => { };
unwrap(b); //compiles
```

F# does not provide support for declaring covariant types, nor does it coerce types without explicit declaration. The reason for this is mostly that covariance leads to degraded type inferencing.

Covariance in F# is possible with [flexible types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/flexible-types).
Here's an example in F# on the `seq` type which is defined as `IEnumerable<out T>`.

```
let s = [1..10] 
let r =  s |> Seq.map(fun _ -> s)

let print1 (v: seq<seq<int>>) = printfn "%A" v
let print2 (v: seq<#seq<_>>) = printfn "%A" v

print1 r //does not compile
print2 r //compiles
```

There is a chance you could make this work if the generic parameters were marked covariant and used flexible types. You could have the interface declarations in C# and reference the assembly in F#.

There is also [mausch/VariantInterfaces](https://github.com/mausch/VariantInterfaces) which modifies the assembly based on a naming convention to add covariant / contravariant declarations, so if you had your type declarations in a separate assembly, you could run it in post-build.